# SAS proc transpose by group with character variables

Tags: sas, transpose

I have a data of three variables. one is id, second is observation count for that id, and third is the value of that observation. I want to transpose the data from long to wide. The issue is that I am getting an error saying my by group is not sorted in ascending order (even though it is). Another issue is that not all values have same amout of observations , please see example below and data structure of what I am looking for

```
data have;
  input id observation value;
  cards;
  1 1 '4.8.9'
  1 2 '4.5.7'
  2 1 '5.0.5'
  3 1 '4.2.0'
  3 2 '4.1.0'
  3 3 '5.1.9';run;
data want;
  input id observation1 observation2 observation3;
  cards;
  1 '4.8.9' '4.5.7' NA
  2 '5.0.5' NA NA
  3 '4.2.0' '4.1.0' '5.1.9'
  ;run;

/* i have tried the following:
proc transpose data=b out=c ;
    by value ;
    id id;
    var value;
run;
proc transpose data=b out=c ;
    by value ;
    id id;
    var observation;
run;
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BY variable is called ID in your example dataset.

Your example data step is not defining VALUE as character.  Also don't indent the in-line data lines.

You can use the `prefix=` option to help name the new variables. Also let's modify the value of OBSERVATION for ID=2 to demonstrate more clearly how the value of OBSERVATION is setting the variable name instead of just the order of the observations in the ID group.  Now the value `'5.0.5'` will be stored in OBSERVATION2 even though it is the first observation for that value of ID.

```
data have;
  input id observation value $;
cards;
1 1 '4.8.9'
1 2 '4.5.7'
2 2 '5.0.5'
3 1 '4.2.0'
3 2 '4.1.0'
3 3 '5.1.9'
;

proc transpose data=have out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=observation;
  by id;
  id observation;
  var value;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    id    observation1    observation2    observation3

 1      1      '4.8.9'         '4.5.7'
 2      2                      '5.0.5'
 3      3      '4.2.0'         '4.1.0'         '5.1.9'
```